# Program asked in a online hiring challenge

Tags: math

Given N integers in the form of A<sub>i</sub> where 1≤i≤N, the goal is to find the M that minimizes the sum of |M-A<sub>i</sub>| and then report that sum.

For example,
Sample Input: 1 2 4 5

Sample Output: 6
Explanation:  One of the best M′s you could choose in this case is 3. 
So the answer = |1−3|+|2−3|+|4−3|+|5−3| = 6.

The approach I used is sort the given input and take the middle number as M.
But I was not able to solve all the test cases. I am unable to find any other approach for this question. Where did I go wrong?(Please help me this question has been bugging me from the past 2 days.Thanks)

Comment: That algorithm should work for the problem you described.  Can you name a test case where it failed?

Comment: @Someone_Else The test cases were hidden. I was only able to see the output

Answer (score 0):

**Can M be any real number or must it be an integer?**

If there are no constraints on M your algorithm must work fine.

If M must be an integer then you have to choose M among floor(The Middle Number) and ceiling(The Middle Number).

In which language did you code up the algorithm?

Comment: I coded in c++.
They did not mention the value M can take.

Comment: Try submitting both the versions. Also provide the constraints on Ai and N or just provide the link to the problem

Comment: I think I got the problem. Try changing all `int` except `int` in `"int main()"` to `long long`. I shall explain if it gets accepted

Comment: The question was asked in the online hiring challenge and they have not made the problem available after the close of the test as I was unable to find the answer to the question so I made a note of the question.
I had used long long int instead of int while solving the question.